# Как сделать двухстороннюю связь в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Есть две таблицы. Нужно, чтобы таблица 1 ссылалась на поле таблицы 2. А таблица 2 ссылалась на поле таблицы 1.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что для создания связи нет: либо первой, либо второй таблицы.

Идея: Есть 3 таблицы: 1)Файлы. 2)Отношения. 3)Сущность. Идея в том, что сущность ссылается на отношение, а отношение ссылается на сущность. Отношение ссылается на файлы. Двухстороння связь нужна, так как у одной записи в сущности могут быть такие колонки: file1, file2, file3. Где каждый file* - как отдельная запись в таблице отношений.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как orm использую [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/).

Comment: Таблица сама по себе никуда не ссылается. Таблица может иметь внешний ключ. Используя внешние ключи, вы можете создавать такие связи, как 1-M, M-M. То, что вы описываете, похоже на 2 связи, но тогда у вас будет проблема курицы и яйца - вы не можете вставить ссылку на запись, если записи ещё нет. Есть вероятность, что у вас ошибка в проектировании БД. Потому, кмк, было бы не плохо добавить больше деталей о вашей задаче в вопрос.

Comment: в вопрос, не в комментарий

Comment: `что сущность сылается на отношение` в чем смысл этого? Вы можете пояснить назначение таблиц и смысл их связей?

Comment: Суть в том, чтобы была история загруженных файлов. Таблиц отношений может быть много: usersRelations, photoRelations и т.д. Иначе, мне в файловую таблицу придется добавлять ссылки на каждую из таблиц. То есть пользователь загрузил фото, на эту таблицу ссылка есть, а во всех остальных будет NULL. Вот, чтобы такой ерунды небыло, нужна одна файловая таблица. А на каждый файл будут ссылки из таблиц - отношений. В таком случае и история будет (через отношения я могу посмотреть запись, что ссылается на файл) и в файлах лишнего не будет.

Comment: отношений кого с кем? И причем тут история? Вы меня ещё больше запутали

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/AqhFzEa.png. Как-то так оно должно выглядеть.

Comment: *Как-то так оно должно выглядеть* Плохо выглядит... денормализованно.

Comment: исходя из вашей картинки ^, которую следует добавить в вопрос, любой файл может являться сразу и видео, и музыкой и картинкой. Также все также не ясно, зачем эти таблицы вообще нужны, чем вам просто одна таблица файлов не подойдет?

Comment: Схема немного упращена. Отношения для фото могут ссылатся на множество таблиц, которые по семантике относятся к фотографиям. Для "видео" и "музыки" ситуация аналогична. А вот в файлах плодить левые таблицы не очень хочется. P.S а что плохого?

Comment: А вообще, использование циклический связей в бд, - это, случаем, не плохая практика?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На уровне MySQL это решается элементарно - сначала создаются таблицы (CREATE TABLE), а потом в них добавляются внешние ключи (ALTER TABLE):

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (id1 INT PRIMARY KEY, id2 INT);
CREATE TABLE tab2 (id2 INT PRIMARY KEY, id1 INT);
ALTER TABLE tab1 ADD FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES tab2 (id2);
ALTER TABLE tab2 ADD FOREIGN KEY (id1) REFERENCES tab1 (id1);
```

Аналогично вставляются записи - сперва INSERT без линков, с NULL в ссылочных полях, а потом UPDATE ссылок.